# How to convert nominal data to numeric in python if dataset has missing value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-mining, missing-data

I am using a binary classification dataset. I want to convert nominal data to numeric.But I have missing value and I dont want to remove them because my goal is to fill theme with KNN method. what should I do to convert them to numeric data ?

```
age | class
------------
 1 |  NAN
 2 |  yes
 3 |  no
 4 |  NAN
 5 |  no
 6 |  NAN
 7 |  no
 8 |  yes
 9 |  no
10 |  NAN
```

**This code dosen't work if dataset has missing value**

```
mapping = {label:idx for idx,label in enumerate(np.unique(df['class']))}
df['class'] = df['class'].map(mapping)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the "yes"/"no" values replaced by numeric values, i.e. 0 and 1?

Comment: @sandertjuh Yes, but I do not know what to do with the missing data because my goal is to find them with KNN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out the nulls before calling unique?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([None, 'yes', 'no', None, 'no',
                   None, 'no', 'yes', 'no', None], columns=['class'])

mapping = {
    label: idx for idx, label in
    enumerate(np.unique(df.loc[df['class'].notnull(), 'class']))
}
df['class'] = df['class'].map(mapping)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   class
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    NaN
4    0.0
5    NaN
6    0.0
7    1.0
8    0.0
9    NaN
```

---

I don't know if you have more classes and that's why you're dynamically assigning `mapping`, but for this particular case:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

Comment: If I have multi nominal feature what should I do Can I use array ?